# How to force Notepad++ to open files only in UTF-8?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, notepad++, ansi

- I have a file with the following code: `print "Hello World"`.
- In `Encoding` section (Notepad++ Menu), `Encode in UTF-8` is chosen.
- I close the file, and open it again: nothing has been changed. Perfect.
- I add some Unicode character, so the code now is: `print "Hello World "`.
- I close the file, and open it again; I see: `print "Hello World рџЂ"`.
- In `Encoding` section, `Encode in ANSI` is chosen.
- Once I forget to change it back to `Encode in UTF-8`, and start typing something, all Unicode characters are lost.

Any changes to `Settings -> Preferences -> New Document -> Encoding` as well as to `// MISC. -> Autodetect character encoding` change nothing for me.

Is there any way to force Notepad++ 7.3.2 to open all files in UTF-8?

Comment: Good reproduction steps.  I have the same behavior and the only way to prevent it was to save the file in UTF-8 with BOM.  I think it is due to that particular emoji.  If I put Chinese in the file it opens correctly.  Seems to be a bug in Notepad++ UTF-8 detection.

Comment: If your toolchain barfs on a BOM, but not UTF-8 in a string literal or comment, you might try putting a BOM inside a comment at the start of the file.  If UTF-8 with BOM just works, though, use that.

Comment: As I see it, the problem starts with the files not being saved in the right encoding. For example, if I save a file in GB2312 (simplified chinese) and reopen the file, it will open in ANSII. I just have to change back the encoding manually and everything is ok. But if I save it in UTF-8, it will always open UTF-8. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem, maybe because of a newer version and a new setting "Apply to opened files":

[image]